Selenium Python: Failing to select a specific auto-suggest dropdown element
I am learning how to use Selenium Python to interact with an auto-suggest dropdown. I am a visually impaired person and I have difficulty in using devtools because it requires mouse operation so I rely heavily on page_source to obtain relevant locators.
I have tried the following 2 methods to get a list of cities but still failed to select a specific city with .click() or Keys.ENTER:
cities = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, "ac_cityname")

cities = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//\*\[contains(text(), 'ckland')\]")

Thanks in advance.
Code
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By 
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException 
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
options = Options()

options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])
options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')
options.add_argument('--incognito')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
from time import sleep
import clipboard


driver.get('https://www.yatra.com/flights')
driver.maximize_window()
sleep(0.5)

#Copy html code to clipboard
clipboard.copy(driver.page_source)

#Click "I Agree" cookies policy button
try:
  driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[contains(text(), 'I Agree')]").click()
  sleep(1)
except NoSuchElementException:
  print("No Cookies Agree button!")

#Find "Depart From" edit box
depart_from = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "BE_flight_origin_city")))

sleep(0.5)

depart_from.click()
sleep(0.5)

depart_from.clear()

#input partial city name "Au" : Auckland
depart_from.send_keys('Au')
sleep(0.5)

print("From:", depart_from.get_attribute('value'))  # return string entered
sleep(0.5)

print("depart_from enabled:", depart_from.is_enabled())  #Verify

cities = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, "ac_cityname")

#I have also tried
#cities = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//*[contains(text(), 'ckland')]")

for city in cities:
  print(city.text)
  if "Auckland" in city.text:
    # I have tries following 2 methods:
    city.click()
    # and 


This was a bugger to figure out. The site is acting weird... normal waits aren't working properly, etc. It's all a lttle "too dynamic" for Selenium default behavior. Anyway, I have some suggestions and then I put the working code at the bottom.
Some suggestions:

You are using a really old version of Selenium because you are able to use the syntax, .find_element_by_xpath(). I would highly suggest that you update to the latest version.
The updated syntax is
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "")
driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "")
driver.find_element(By.ID, "")

So... different but not drastically different. See the docs for more info.

time.sleep() is a bad practice. It's a "dumb" wait... if the element is ready early, it still waits X seconds. If you need to wait, use a WebDriverWait instead. You are already using it some... just replace all the sleeps with waits. Your script will be faster and more consistently reliable.
Having said that, I did put some sleeps in here because proper waits weren't working at times. My general rule is to find a way to use waits every time. When I run out of ideas and can't get a WebDriverWait to work, then I fall back to sleeps as a last resort.

When using a WebDriverWait or really anything you can reuse, store it in a variable so it can be reused, e.g.
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
depart_from = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "BE_flight_origin_city")))

It keeps you from spending time and resources repeatedly reinstantiating the same object, etc.

In Selenium terms, presence means that the element exists in the DOM but not that it's visible or clickable. You generally shouldn't wait for presence. If you want to click an element, wait for it to be clickable using EC.element_to_be_clickable(). If you want to otherwise interact with an element, wait for visible using EC.visibility_of_element_located().



The working code...
url = 'https://www.yatra.com/flights'
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get(url)

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

# Copy html code to clipboard
clipboard.copy(driver.page_source)

# Click "I Agree" cookies policy button
try:
    driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//button[contains(text(), 'I Agree')]").click()
except NoSuchElementException:
    print("No Cookies Agree button!")

# Find "Depart From" edit box
airport_name = 'Auckland'
depart_from = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "BE_flight_origin_city")))
time.sleep(1)
depart_from.click()
time.sleep(1)
depart_from.send_keys(airport_name)
time.sleep(1)
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, f"//p[@class='ac_cityname'][contains(.,'{airport_name}')]").click()

